# Past and future date allow only 12 months from selected date

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I use the [bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#quick-reference) library.

This screenshot shows a default pre-selected date:

[image]

My problem is that I can change the date to something like `2019-12-01`, which is not within the specified range.

[image]

A future date can be changed to `2024-12-01`.

[image]

I am expecting to be able to change the date only 12 months from the pre-selected date in past and future.

Here is my code:

```js
$('#can_edit_doj').datepicker({
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    autoclose: true,
    endDate: '+365d',
    startDate: '-365d
});
```

Comment: _Which_ datepicker library is this supposed to be, there are probably more of these than days in a year ...

Comment: Am using bootstrap-datepicker.js

Comment: Relative values for `startDate` and `endDate` options are referring to the current date, today - and not what other date the field might contain initially. So you will have to determine what the date +/- one year for your given date is - and then set start- and enddate accordingly.

Comment: Yes I am already set startdate and end date. But is not working 

  $('#can_edit_doj').datepicker({               
     format: "yyyy-mm-dd",               
     autoclose: true,               
     endDate: '+365d',               
     startDate: '-365d  
});

Comment: I _just_ told you what is wrong about setting it like that, did I not?

Comment: If I set startdate and enddate I can able to change to prev date till 2019. And past also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As CBroe pointed out in his comment, *relative* `startDate` and `endDate` values (like `+365d`) refer to the current date.

Instead, you can use *absolute* values, calculated from your initial value.
For example:

```js
const initialDate = new Date("2021/05/07");
const dayRange = 365;
const rangeInMillis = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * dayRange;
const startDate = new Date(initialDate.getTime() - rangeInMillis);
const endDate = new Date(initialDate.getTime() + rangeInMillis);
$("#can_edit_doj").datepicker({
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    autoclose: true,
    startDate: startDate,
    endDate: endDate
});
$("#can_edit_doj").datepicker("setDate", initialDate);
```